# Requirements check failed for JDK 8 NULL

Tags: java, cordova

I am aware similar questions have been asked before, but I cannot seem to succeed at building an app using 'cordova build android'. It keeps showing:

Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: null

I reinstalled Java SDK multiple times, added the system variable and there are NO other versions installed. Anyone any thoughts?

Comment: If you run `java -version`, what happens?

Comment: Between Java SE 8 and Java SE 9 the **internal** version code changed from `1.8` to `9`. Old software is not able to detect that Java SE 9 is newer than Java SE 8.

Comment: Running java -version shows 1.8.0_281.

Comment: Probably it can't find the JDK, try setting the [`JAVA_HOME` variable](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#setting-environment-variables) to the base directory of your JDK installation.

Comment: Already did as I said, added the system variable